# Why this code prints single characters instead of the word?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

```
char em[] = {'no','yes','maybe','kinda','btw'};
for (int k = 0;k<2;k++){
    printf("%c", em[rand()%5+1]);
}
```

This code should print in output `"no"`, `"yes"`, `"maybe"`, `"kinda"` or `"btw"`. But when I run it, it prints one single characters for example `'o'` or `'k'` ecc... Why?

Comment: Multi-character constants... And you are printing only one using `"%c"`

Comment: To begin with, e.g. `'no'` versus `"no"`... Single versus double quotes. Please take some time to read your text books a little more.

Comment: `em[rand()%5+1]` is out of range too. It should be `em[rand()%5]`. You can access a 5-element array with indexes `0` to `4`, not with indexes `1` to `5`.

Comment: checking the warnings is generally a good reflex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got `em` declared as an array of characters and yet you've got what look like Python-style strings in its definition.

In C, character strings require double-quotes.  Single quotes are **only** for individual characters.

What you want is

```
char *em[] = {"no","yes","maybe","kinda","btw"};
```

That will make `em` an array of character pointers.

Finally, you need to use `%s` instead of `%c` to print out strings.